# List/view/clear persistent variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, global-variables

How does one list/view/clear persistent variables in MATLAB? I'd like to see persistent variables not for a particular function, but for all functions that have persistent variables currently in memory.

I've tried things like `whos('persistent')` and `whos('global')` with no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Persistent variables can only be declared inside a function so you'll need to call `whos` in there. Once the variable exists, you'll see that `whos` shows that it is `'persistent'` under the `'Attributes'` column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply horchler. I am looking for a way to list all functions which have persistent variables in memory, and list their persistent variables. I realize that you can use clear as you described below to clear persistent variables, but this would require you to know beforehand which functions have persistent variables.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way. You might contact The MathWorks and put in a service request. One potentially useful function is [`inmem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inmem.html), but it will just tell you which functions, mex files, and classes have been compiled and loaded into memory. I suppose you could use it as a starting point and parse the function names returned looking for `persistent` (maybe with `mlintmex('-lex','filename.m')`), but that's quite a hack.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to clear a [`persistent`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) from outside of the function within which it's defined, then you need to [`clear`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html) the function itself:

```
clear functionNameWithPersistentVariable
```

Or clear all ([unlocked](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mlock.html)) functions from memory:

```
clear functions
```

If the function in question is actually a method of a [class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/class-definition-and-organization.html), you may need to use `clear classes` instead. See also [this table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html#inputarg_ItemType) in the documentation for `clear`.

Within the function itself you may be able to use `whos` and something like the suggestion in [this Matlab Central answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16799#answer_22660). Unfortunately, I don't know of any elegant documented way to find or list functions or persistent variables that are currently in memory.